# Модуль Paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

Есть небольшой скрипт. который по ssh подключается к оборудованию и достает от туда данные через функцию. Само подключение и описание функции лежит в другом файле(отдельном от основного скрипта). Когда я запускаю основной скрипт у меня сразу же создается соединение с по SSH хотя функция еще не вызывалась и потом спустя какое то время приходит
`Socket exception: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение (10054)`

Как можно сделать что бы соединение происходило только в момент вызова функции?
Вот как выглядит мой код

````
import time
from keyboa import keyboa_maker

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname="192.168.0.1",
                   username="admin",
                   password="admin",
                   look_for_keys=False,
                    allow_agent=False)
ssh = ssh_client.invoke_shell()

def ssh_onuState(olt):
    ssh.send('terminal length 0\n')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ssh.send('sho gpon onu state gpon-olt_' + olt + '\n')
    time.sleep(1)


    with open('register.txt', 'wb') as output_file:  # запись в файл
        output_file.write(ssh.recv(60000))
    ssh.close()```
````

Comment: Переместить ssh_client.connect и ssh=ssh_client.invoke_shell()  в тело функции?

Comment: У меня несколько функций. Получается мне надо в каждую засовывать. Получается нагромождение кода. Меня интересует можно ли сам коннект вывести в функцию и просто вызывать ее в другой функции...

Comment: Можно все что вам угодно обернуть в функцию и вызывать по мере надобности.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как тогда завернуть connect в отдельную функцию.